# Unable to view tablespace name for a partitioned table

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I am unable to get the tablespace information for a partitioned table.

I have tried querying tablespace_name from dba_tables but the value was null. Let me know the reason to this and also from where can I view the tablespace_name for a partitioned table.

```
select tablespace_name 
from dba_tables 
where table_name = 'XXXXX';
```

The result was null.

Please let me know how can I get the tablespace information coz I am trying to move the partitions to a new tablespace.Also let me know the impact of it.

Answer (score 2):

The reason is that you could have each partition in a different tablespace, so the information at a table level does not exist and you need to check the partitions.

[Oracle doc](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25523/part_admin002.htm#i1007318) for this

You may need [DBA_TAB_PARTITIONS](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/refrn/DBA_TAB_PARTITIONS.html)

```
select tablespace_name
from dba_tab_partitions
where table_name='...'
  and table_owner = '...'
```

Comment: yeahh true....Also please let me know is there any impact if I transfer these partition to a new tablespace.